# mysql syntax error for timestamp

Tags: sql, mysql

I have this piece of SQL that is being fed to Mysql.

```
CREATE TABLE pn_history(
 member INT,
 action INT,
 with INT,
 timestamp DATETIME,
 details VARCHAR(256)
)
```

But is comes back as an error about the syntax.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'with INT,
timestamp DATETIME,
details VARCHAR(256)
)' at line 4
```

Why is this failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the name of the `with` column. Change the name into something like `withValue`.

```
CREATE TABLE pn_history(
 member INT,
 action INT,
 withValue INT,
 timestamp DATETIME,
 details VARCHAR(256)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Both 'with' and 'timestamp' are [reserved words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_word) in MySQL. So to get this to work, you'd need to escape each one:

```
CREATE TABLE pn_history(
 member INT,
 action INT,
 `with` INT,
 `timestamp` DATETIME,
 details VARCHAR(256)
)
```

Really though, you need to consider changing the names of your columns [identifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html).

Read more about [MySQL Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html).

**EDIT:** Actually, `TIMESTAMP` is not a reserved word. The documentation says:

> MySQL allows some keywords to be used
>   as unquoted identifiers because many
>   people previously used them. Examples
>   are those in the following list:
>
> - `ACTION`
> - `BIT`
> - `DATE`
> - `ENUM`
> - `NO`
> - `TEXT`
> - `TIME
> - `TIMESTAMP`

So I guess that means peer pressure took `TIMESTAMP` off the reserved word list. Hah!

Answer (score 0):

timestamp is a keyword (it is a data type in mysql) which may be causing you problems.

I would suggest using a different name, but if it must be named timestamp, try using backticks to quote it.